# Design pattern for controlling access to the service

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture

I need to design architecture for application with `Player`.

`Player` purpose is playing music. `Player` has controls like play, stop, pause, loadSong.

`Player` can be used by `User` and `APController`. `APController`  and `User` can use `Player` but `User` has higher priority than `APController`. If `APController` is using `Player` to play some music and `User` want to play different song this should be possible without waiting. From the other side if `User` is playing song via `Player` then `APController` want's to play some song then it must wait until `User` will finish playing with `Player` so it can go to idle state. Think about `APController` like some AI-User who knows how to use `Player` but this AI-User must respect `User` priority.

How to design access to this `Player`. I think I need some coordinator object and `APController` and `User` need to talk via this coordinator with `Player`. I need also some way to send feedback to coordinator when the `Player` is idle (means `User` end interaction with it) and let `APController` use it if `APController` want to use it.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. STart writing some code, and come back if you have a concrete question.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like a mediator could help you. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern